# ASP.NET MVC DropDownList SelectedValue into a ViewBag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this drop down list:

```
@{ var listItems = new List<MVC_WebUI.Models.SelectedListItems> 
                { new MVC_WebUI.Models.SelectedListItems { Text = "---Select---", Value = "0" }, 
                       new MVC_WebUI.Models.SelectedListItems { Text = "Answer 1", Value = "1" }, 
                       new MVC_WebUI.Models.SelectedListItems { Text = "Answer 2", Value = "2" }, 
                       new MVC_WebUI.Models.SelectedListItems { Text = "Answer 3", Value = "3" }, 
                        new MVC_WebUI.Models.SelectedListItems { Text = "Answer 4", Value = "4" }                        
                       }; 
                     }
@Html.DropDownList("Answer", new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text"), new { onchange = "getAlldata()" })
```

Can you please explain, how to get the selected value into a Viewbag variable?
Thank You!!

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: its still an unclear question my friend

Comment: Wrong way of going about.. You should be populating the dropdown list from your controllers and using `@Html.DropDownListFor` to create a dropdown list. The selected value will then be posted back to the controller when the user submits the form.

Comment: how do i get this value into a viewbag or a session?

Comment: @Dayan... in an MVC approach, you pass a Model to the View... and if the user submit the form, the view send values as a model to the Controller Action. The ViewBag is a helper to pass values from Action to the View, but once user select options you need to post it to the server (there you can do whatever you like with that).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why u need it in view bag Just try like below

Note : In below i have mention ControllerName that must the Name of your controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MethodName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @{ var listItems = new List<MVC_WebUI.Models.SelectedListItems> { 
                   new MVC_WebUI.Models.SelectedListItems { Text = "---Select---", Value = "0" }, 
                   new MVC_WebUI.Models.SelectedListItems { Text = "Answer 1", Value = "1" }, 
                   new MVC_WebUI.Models.SelectedListItems { Text = "Answer 2", Value = "2" }, 
                   new MVC_WebUI.Models.SelectedListItems { Text = "Answer 3", Value = "3" }, 
                   new MVC_WebUI.Models.SelectedListItems { Text = "Answer 4", Value = "4" }                        
            }; 
      }

 @Html.DropDownList("Answer", new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text"), new { onchange = "getAlldata()" }) 
        <input type="submit" value="Click" />

}
```

And your Action method bust be like below.

Then you can able to get it in the below method.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MethodName(String Answer)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ViewName");
    }
```

Comment: If it is use full, just mark answer as correct by clicking the up arrow front of the 0, which is in left side of my code like menu